# How does Yablo's paradox affect the theory of truth?

Tags: metaphysics, truth, paradox, theory

Question: What does [Yablo's paradox](https://iep.utm.edu/yablo-pa/) tell us about what a theory of truth should look like?

I have been reading [Leitgeb's *What Theories of Truth Should be Like*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228673686_What_Theories_of_Truth_Should_Be_Like_But_Cannot_Be), and he discusses what a 'good' theory of truth should look like.

Obviously, we know a consistent theory of truth does not satisfy all the properties we would like it to have (e.g. having a truth predicate with no type restriction and classical logic as the base logic results in inconsistency). So Leitgeb has been considering what combinations are possible, and one of them is as follows:

1. If a theory of truth is added to mathematical or empirical theories, it
   should be possible to prove the latter true
2. The truth predicate should not be subjected to any type restrictions
3. Truth should be compositional
4. The theory should allow for standard interpretations
5. The outer logic and the inner logic should coincide (the former being the base logic, and the latter being the logic the truth predicate is a part of)
6. The outer logic should be classical

When talking about 'standard interpretation', Leitgeb seems to have standard interpretation of arithmetic in his mind, because he wrote:

> For example, in describing an elementary mathematical fact by means of
> the sentence ‘2 + 2 = 4’ we interpret ‘2’ and ‘4’ as referring to
> natural numbers, ‘+’ as denoting the addition of natural numbers, and
> ‘=’ as expressing the identity relation for natural numbers. When the
> arithmetician says ‘for all x, for all y: x + y = y + x’, then she
> understands ‘x’ and ‘y’ as ranging over natural numbers and only
> natural numbers; and so on.

> But if we are not careful enough, our
> intended interpretation of a formal language can be excluded by the
> theory that we formulate in this language and that we hold true.
> Standard examples are all first-order theories of the following kind:
> they are formulated in the language of arithmetic; they include an
> infinite sequence of sentences of the form A(1), A(2), A(3), . . . ;
> at the same time they also include the sentence ‘not for all x: A(x)’. (It seems that Leitgeb is referring to omega inconsistency here)

But as shown by McGee, even though the resulting theory would be consistent, the combination of 3 and 5 requires sacrificing 4. As Leitgeb explains:

> This follows from the existence of a self-referential sentence which
> says that not all applications of the truth predicate (with quotation
> marks) to itself are true. Analogous results can be derived from the
> existence of an ‘ungrounded’ infinite sequence of sentences such that
> each of the sentences in the sequence expresses that not all of its
> subsequent sentences are true (Yablo was the first to discover
> paradoxes of this sort (see ‘Paradox without Self-Reference’)

I don't quite understand what he is saying here. As far as I know, the revelation of Yablo's paradox is that a theory of truth cannot get rid of paradoxes simply by prohibiting self-reference, because Yablo's is (allegedly) non-self referential. But I don't see how this relates to a theory having standard interpretations.

Comment: Standard interpretations refers to the [prominent theories of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth#Major_theories): correspondence, coherence, deflation, pragmatism, etc. Any theory of truth must accomodate them?

Comment: Added link to reference and suggested tags.

Comment: @Constantly I don't want to confuse you more but given that Leitgeb insists on "standard interpretation", did he say whether a theory of truth should be true?

Comment: Leitgeb's above spec for his desiderata as a theory of truth sounds modeled upon categorical logic such as topos which has an internal logic, and he just wishes to add Tarski's "undefinable" T-predicate as part of it and what remains coincide with the external classic logic. Your above Leitgeb's explanation "a self-referential sentence" refers to the Liar sentence, so his conclusion is whether self-reference or not (Yablo sentences), these paradoxes all imply inconsistency between 3,5 and 4 simply because truth from composition as implicit in these cases lead to paradoxes as we already know...

Comment: so the "standard interpretation" here most likely means Tarski's T-schema which is intrinsically truth-compositional, you can review one of your previous [post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82190/in-the-context-of-philosophical-logic-what-does-extra-logical-mean) for the reason...

Comment: @JD Hi, I think by standard interpretation Leitgeb here meant standard interpretation of arithmetic, I've edited my post to add more details

Comment: @Speakpigeon I am afraid I don't understand what you mean, could you elaborate please?

Comment: If I understand this right then the point is that if truth is compositional and outer logic coincides with inner logic then theories that can express Yablo's paradox, or perhaps even all ω-inconsistent theories, provide a counterexample to 4. I.e. they rule out the intended interpretation, which they, supposedly, formalize. Since a theory of truth is supposed to be joinable to any object theory by 1 Yablo paradox tells us that it cannot satisfy the conjunction of 1,3,4 and 5.

Comment: @Constantlyconfused What do you think? Should a theory of truth be true? Don't you think it is a little problematic to have a theory of truth? Once you claim that standard interpretations apply, we should be able to think of the theory of truth as true or false, but people who don't buy your theory won't apply the criteria of truth assumed in this theory. In other word, the logic of it becomes self-validating. X implies X.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you that makes a lot of sense; so to make sure I understand correctly, a theory of truth that satisfies the conditions above can express the Yablo paradox. Now, the Yablo sequence of sentences goes up to ω, and this sequence is consistent but ω-inconsistent, thus it only has non-standard models. But because of this, it means we must give up 4. Does this sound right?

Comment: Yes, that's my reading of the quotes in the post, but I did not read the papers themselves. For example, I am not entirely sure whether the argument about standard interpretations goes through for ω-inconsistent theories generally, or just for those that encode Yablo's paradox specifically.

Comment: After seeing your added content, sounds like Leitgeb is describing a new kind of semantic theory of (arithmetic) truth as a Tarski variant to be *able* to express both circular Liar and non-circular Yablo kinds of paradox. But to achieve so with the fact that Yablo paradox implies ω-inconsistency, one has to give up the standard Model N since it demands ω-consistency. And to express Liar paradox under this new theory of truth one can treat it as a fixed point of the negation of the truth-predicate ¬T(gn(L)) in the internal logic similar in truth-undefinability thm under Tarski's truth theory..

Comment: But I see a potential weak point in McGee's critique, as your Yablo ref mentioned to arrive at line 8 in the formal proof ones needs invoke ∀-intro rule. But as a well-known fact in 1st-order PA this rule is invalid in the presence of many non-standard models. To overcome this ones needs to add a new infinitary ω-rule of inference. So if this new envisioned theory of truth still based on classic FOL per above spec, it actually cannot express Yablo paradox (your ref also mentioned Priest doesn't think it's a real paradox). If Yablo case is not paradox in FOL, McGee's conclusion doesn't hold...

Comment: I would like to add that I have just found out about Jeff Ketland's paper, which includes detailed proofs on why Yablo's set of sentences are ω-inconsistent (while staying syntactically consistent, according to Ketland).

https://www.impan.pl/~kz/truthseminar/KetlandSyntheseYablo.pdf